# unable to set header and content in the same alignment using ionic 2

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework, ionic2

I ma displaying the dynamic data into the  it is displaying in the below format

[image: table data dsplayed in ion-col]

here if us see the alignment between the header and content we can clearly see the mis match and in the body also i got any data with large content it is displaying in the below format

[image: content in the body if any large word occurs it is displaying like this]

below is my html code

```
<ion-grid class="g-table">
      <ion-row wrap>
        <ion-col>
          Names
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col>
          Qty
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col>
          Amount
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col text-center>
         Status
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col>
          Reason
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col>
          Name
        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
      <div class="tbody">
      <ion-row *ngFor="let value of Data" wrap >
        <ion-col>
          {{value.Name}}
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col>
          {{value.Qty}}
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col>
          {{value.Amount | number:'.2'}}
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col text-center>
          {{value.Status}}
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col>
          {{value.Reason}}
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col>
          {{value.Name}}
        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
      <ion-row >
        <ion-col>
          Total
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col>

        </ion-col>
        <ion-col>
          {{Total|number:'.2'}}
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col>

        </ion-col>
        <ion-col>

        </ion-col>
        <ion-col>

        </ion-col>

      </ion-row>
```

Comment: im not sure ur supposed to use tables like this with a grid

Comment: what is css for `<div class="tbody">` and `g-table`?

Comment: i think you need to remove `<div class="tbody">`

Comment: but having a requirement  ok i will try to remove the css files too